# Count and display button click on page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, counter

I am looking for a very simple solution to tracking and displaying the number of clicks of a button on a webpage. I searched Google and all the solutions I found were far more complicated than what I am looking for.

Basically all I need it to do is track every time a single button is clicked, store the value of total clicks in a database and then display that value on the same page. I'm guessing I will need to use PHP/MySQL to accomplish this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: What code you tried so far?

Comment: You could use jQuery. Set a counter variable like `var i = 0;` thenuse click event on document and have ajax submit, either on the click event, or on a timer. `$(document).on('click', function(e) { i++; /* preform ajax call to PHP */ });`. Then have your php record `i` to your db

Comment: I haven't tried any code because all the solutions I've found so far were overly complicated for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: [***Suggestion with small example here***](http://jsfiddle.net/cG3KJ/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with PHP/MySQL/jQuery. I haven't tested any of this code and it won't be very effective at tracking bursts of fast clicks, but it should get you started:

- [Include jQuery in the footer of your webpage](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)
- Include `click.js` (below) beneath the jquery call
- Set up an SQL table called `click_log` that contains `user_id (INT)` and `time (DATETIME)`

Include this code at the bottom of your document. It feeds the increment script a user ID (assuming you have a user's ID handy as variable):

```
<script>
    $(function () {

      // Event handler for the click
      $(document).click(function(e){

        // Feed the increment function the user's ID
        increment(<?= $user_id ?>);

      });
    })
</script>
```

Include a counter `div` wherever you want the total count displayed, and include `get_count.php` in it:

```
<div id="counter">
    <?php include("get_count.php?user_id=".$user_id); ?>
</div>
```

**click.js** - jQuery function to call the increment script below via AJAX

```
$(function () {

  // Define an increment function to accept a user_id
  function increment(user_id){

      // Create a data object
      data = {
        user_id = user_id
      }

      // Deliver the payload
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "increment.php",
        dataType:"JSON", 
        data: data, 
        success:function(response){
          $("#counter").empty().load("get_count.php?user_id="+user_id);
        }
      });

  }
}
```

**increment.php** - PHP script to register a click in database from an AJAX request

```
<?php

  // Set the header to accept JSON
  header("Content-type: application/json");

  // Insert your database connection here (should probably use mysqli)
  $host     =  "localhost"; // or IP or whatever
  $db_user  =  "admin";
  $db_pass  =  "password";
  $db_name  =  "your_db";
  mysql_connect($servername, $db_user, $db_pass) or mysql_error();
  mysql_select_db($db_name) or db_name();

  // Grab user id from post data
  $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];

  // Write the query
  $sql = "INSERT INTO click_log (user_id, time) VALUES ('".$user_id."', CURRENT_DATE());"

  // Encode a JSON response if the query is successful
  if(mysql_query($sql)){
    echo json_encode("Success");
  }


?>
```

**get_count.php** - File to load in your counter div that displays total clicks by user

```
<?php 

  // Get the user id from the URL ($_GET)
  $user_id = $_GET["user_id"];

  // Write the SQL to count the number of rows ('clicks') with that user
  $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM click_log WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."';";

  // Run the query
  $result = mysql_query($count_sql);

  // Format the result and set it a variable
  $total_clicks = mysql_result($result, 0);

  // Print the total clicks by that user
  echo $total_clicks;

?>
```

Hope this helps get you started! :)

Comment: `$(document).click` or `$(window).click` might prove more accurate as CSS may sometimes allow `body` to not cover whole site area. ***Also***, great answer and good on ya takin the time to write all that up, lol!

Comment: Also, I've clarified the first block of code by adding the `<script>` tags. @APAD1

Answer (score 0):

Here is about as simple as it gets for saving a number on the server. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp Or in other words its not that simple.  Try out some code and then ask a more specific question.

Note w3schools isn't the best html resource but it does give

Answer (score 0):

I found a text document solution which fits my needs perfectly. I've implemented it, but the problem is that the action remains in the URL after the button is initially clicked so all you need to do to increase the count is to refresh the page. What would be the easiest way to prevent this?

**PHP:**

```
if ( ! file_exists('./count.txt'))
{
    file_put_contents('./count.txt','0');
}

if (trim($_GET['action']) == 'increment')
{
    counter('increment');
}

function counter($action)
{
    if ($action == 'count')
    {
        return file_get_contents('./count.txt');
    }
    else
    {
        file_put_contents('./count.txt', (string) (((int) file_get_contents('./count.txt')) + 1));
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="button"><a href="index.php?action=increment#page5">Click Here</a></span>
```

Comment: You have zero clue what you're doing, correct? It's ok if that's true, but it would really help us here if you'd be that honest and let us know you need some beginner site references. I have a feeling you're already in over your head. I would suggest Googleing some things like `How to build a website with PHP` and `How to use jQuery`, as it will be much faster and easier for you to learn than Vanilla JS. And if you want Ajax, you'll want jQuery, it'll keep you from having more questions.

Comment: In over my head with a simple PHP counter? I don't think so. I'm not trying to build an entire PHP site, just a small chunk of code to track and store button counts. I think it's pretty clear that I don't have "zero clue what I'm doing."

Comment: Oh I see, so you just want to count the button clicks. It didn't seem to say that before. Dude ... you're going way overboard for this. If all you're doing is counting the button clicks, then you need to use Ajax and not count the file loads(which is what you're doing above). My example in comments at top still should give you a small clue, but basically, just dont let the "anchor" go anywhere. Have it call ajax instead, then have your php count that hit as a click (as it will be) save to DB, then decide if to reroute or simply return a calue to the AJAX JS

Comment: Thanks SpYk3HH, I will play around with it a bit.